# Move Robot Base

Tags: ros, base-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to move robot_base to some position. I am reading this page http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup and wondering what the difference between 2.4 and 2.5 is. I mean one way I can do is to publish velocity command to base_controller/command but while I am reading this page, it seems like another way I can do is to publish to "odom". I am not sure what is the right way to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200368/move-robot-base/) by [newcastle](https://answers.ros.org/users/21270/newcastle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The odometry source (2.4) is the result (displacement) of the command (cmd_vel) that is executed by the base controller (2.5).  So you tell your robot to go 1 m/s and the odometry source reports that has travelled 1 m after 1s, 2m after 2s, etc.  Is that clear?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [newcastle](https://answers.ros.org/users/21270/newcastle/) on 2015-01-04**:
so if I want to move the robot 1m, which way is better between using (cmd_vel) or publishing to odom?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-01-04**:
odometry is the estimate of the pose of the robot so publishing to odom will not move the robot.  Publishing a cmd_vel and checking the odometry estimate can ensure you stop when you get to 1m.

**Comment by [newcastle](https://answers.ros.org/users/21270/newcastle/) on 2015-01-04**:
yea, that makes sense. However, over here, under "Creating our own odometry," they seems to have a way to move the robot by publishing to odom.pose.pose